# Preventing CCleaner Alert window

Tags: ccleaner

At the advanced menu of [CCleaner](https://www.piriform.com/ccleaner) I checked “Hide warning messages” however the CCleaner Alert window appears at the screen right corner.

How can I uninstall that CCleaner alert window?

Comment: I think your referring to notifications not the warnings. It is possible you could effect that in the windows system itself "Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Notification Area Icons" Accessed via the notifications tray in the bottom right "customise notification icons", "Hide icon and notifications" ,But I do not see ccleaner as one of the notification items shown on this computer. The "warnings" are the requesters that show up as a child of the main ccleaner window. The program itself does not have an option for the notifications, only warnings.

Comment: In Ccs own advanced options selecting to "minimise to systray" would put an icon in the notifications (when it is running), then maybe you could disable notifications after it exists?  Untested.

Comment: @pyscogeek, I tried your advice and sounds ok. Let me try a little to see if that reappears. thanks

Comment: @pysogeek, bad: the CCleaner "Alert" (that's the right word) still appears... Please advise

Comment: Must be thier own little window :-( I know some ways to hide a programs altogether, but it is something they (piraform) should put a switch in for.  Assuming a solution was one more utility item that messes with windows (general), What is the method your using to run the program, that brings up the Alert Window. I have seen it before but it does not come up in the method I am using.  Is it Trash context menu item?  Automated  at startup  or scheduled?

Comment: @psycogeek do you mean the problem is of piraform? quite bad if they don't have that option. I do have CCleaner running at the startup. But if I believe that at many times that little window appears and bothers. I do presentations so it is not good that... still any solution?